# SSD1306 128x32 Connector

Tags: connector, oled

What's the name of connector which can be used here?

I know that I can always solder it to PCB, but I was looking for more "elegant" solution, and I remember seeing these connectors before on PCB's but I don't know how to search for them (under which name):

[image]

Comment: FPC Connector? It's for flat ribbons.

Comment: Yes, that's the one that I was looking for! :)

Comment: search the web for the technical drawings for that display. ... there may be a part number for the connector in the drawings

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Connector for the display is this: https://www.buydisplay.com/default/14-pins-0-5mm-pitch-top-contact-zif-connector-fpc-connector
or search `FPC 14x0.5`

## update

0.5mm pitch has different (but similar) display: https://www.buydisplay.com/default/white-128x32-0-91-inch-i2c-iic-serial-wearable-oled-display-ssd1306

As CalumNicoll mentioned, display from question has 0.62mm pitch, for this you need different connector like FPC 14x0.62

Comment: These ssd1306 are usually 0.62mm pitch and thus would not fit.  Try lw06121-14 connector instead.

Comment: Yes, thanks for info, you are right, it is 0.62mm!

Comment: @CalumNicoll do you have link, where it is possible to buy this connector?

Comment: added it to answer as easier to see than comments!

Answer (score 0):

The 0.62mm pitch connector is very niche - but wenda electronics co (chinese firm)  - make them - part no lw06121-14

Would expect most chinese assemblers would be able to source them no problem - but here's an alibaba link too.

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Wenda-new-design-0-62mm-pitch_60732983697.html