# How do I connect display to board

Tags: connector, display, oled

I’m experimenting when some OLED displays similar to [this](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/790-EAW096016-XALW) and here’s the [data sheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/127/W096016-XA-1275487.pdf). My question is how do I connect the display to the PCB? I’m unfamiliar with the flat ribbon type cable and how to connect it to a PCB. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To understand your question the reader has to follow two links. You have a better chance of an answer if you post enough information in the question that it stands on its own and it may be still useful when the links die. Hit the [edit] link ...

Comment: Think you need an exotic Wenda FFC 14 x 0.62mm connector -- FFC is commonly used with 1mm or 0.5mm pitch, but that 0.62mm lead pitch is pretty rare. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/441393/35022 -- looks like they don't have any USA distributors, you have to go through alibaba.

Comment: Thanks @MarkU . I don’t have to use that specific display, I was mostly looking for the name of the connector. Is the connector name FFC or FPC?

Comment: FFC = Flat Flex Cable, FPC = Flexible Printed Circuit. So use the search term "FFC Connector".